# Is my German Shepherd teething or sick?

Tags: dogs, health, purebred

So I have a 5 month old German Shepherd and lately she hasn't had her usual appetite, she would only eat her food if fed by hand. She is also losing weight because of the reduced appetite.

What is more, she recently lost two teeth - it happened this weekend.

**Does anyone know how to feed her, make sure that she eats and when she will have her regular appetite back?**

**Also, considering the weight loss issue, should I increase the number of her daily meals to 4?**

Answer (score 2):

She needs to be seen by a veterinarian immediately. These symptoms could be any number of diseases which affect puppies.

Comment: thank you , she has  gotten her appetite back, and eating well .  she is also drinking well so I think she is just teething But I Did schedule a appointment to the vet for this week

Comment: Great! Hope it goes well.

Answer (score 1):

If a dog doesn't eat well nor drink well then it is highly likely she's not right. This is one of the ways they tell us. I strongly suggest a vet's visit. 
There are lots of other possible reasons but I would eliminate that first.
http://www.m.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/dog-not-eating-possible-causes-and-appetite-solutions